# How to build ERC20 based stablecoin?

Tags: ether, erc-20, stablecoins

I want to build **stablecoin** for my college project. I am thinking of developing `ERC20` token pegged with fiat currency. Can someone please suggest me best tutorials/guides to build stablecoin on `ERC20`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes a coin to be a stablecoin is an ability to exchange it for certain amount of underlying stable asset (fiat currency in your case), and people's trust that this ability will persist in future.

If your stablecoin is to be implemented as ERC-20 token on Ethereum, then the token smart contract does not need to have any special functionality.  Just simple token with mint/burn ability should work.

Simply issue tokens in exchange for fiat, and promise to pay fiat for tokens burned by the token holders, and your token will be stablecoin similar to [Tether USDT Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code).